# Native raspberry 64 OS raspivid: cannot execute binary file

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi4, picamera, raspistill, raspivid

OS:

Linux raspberrypi 5.10.35-v8+ #1417 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 7 17:44:55 BST 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Reinstall doesn't work at all

Can't execute rasp:

[image]

```
/opt/vc/bin/raspivid: /opt/vc/bin/raspivid: cannot execute binary file
```

ffmpeg works fine.